# What is the little "a:" for/mean in GoLand?

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland

In the JetBrains GoLand IDE, when I type a basic "Hello, World!" example, there is a small `a:` in front of the string passed to `fmt.Println()` that is added by the IDE. What does it mean and what is its purpose?

[image: small a]

I could not find the answer in the documentation.

Comment: It’s the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are known as [**parameter hints**](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/features/), and they are common in JetBrains IDEs. Basically, it's the name of the parameter in the definition of `fmt.Println`. See [the official docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println), where the first parameter is named `a` in the definition of `Println`.